# feedwordpress - all my feeds have disappeared

Tags: wordpress, plugins, syndication-feed

I am using feedwordpress Version 2012.1218 on my site and had about 6 different feeds I was syndicating from. For some reason today I logged into my wordpress site and all my feeds are gone, but I am still syndicating all the feeds. So basically everything still works but I can't see my feeds anymore. It shows that I have none. Only thing I could find on the net was this

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-feedwordpress-feeds-are-disappearing?replies=2

but no help. Anyone use feedwordpress that might have some wisdom? I have uninstalled it and downloaded the latest version and still having the issues. There were some Memory Limit issues suggested as well so I added

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

to the top of my wp-config.php page. Still no go....

anything else I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Feed Wordpress on many sites and recently had a similar situation (some 700 feeds disappeared!). In my situation, a hard disk issue was causing a lot of server crashes, and the wp_links table in the database was not closed correctly and was hung. Running a repair on the table restored all my links.

FWP stores information about the feeds in the wordpress links, so you can check if this was te same situation by going to your links in the dashboard- in my case all of the links (one per feed) were gone as well.

It was a matter of going into phpMyAdmin and running a repair on the wp_links table (actually it is better to run a check on all tables, because our wp_options table was crashed as well).